# Macro fails using arrows

Tags: macro

I want to escape in my file some of the `"` by `\"`.

For example, I want to transform `foo"bar"xyz"` to `foo\"bar\"xyz\"`.

### Attempt 1 :

1. search for `"` (typing `/"`)
2. create my macro (typing `qai\`, `Esc`, `RightArrow`, `nq`)
3. use my macro with `@a`. Unfortunately, this last step failed.

### Attempt 2 :

1. search for `"` (typing `/"`)
2. create my macro (typing `qai\`, `Esc`, `l`, `nq`)
3. use my macro with `@a`. Works like a charm.

### Question :

Why this macro fails when using arrows, and works perfectly when using `l`?

This is the first time it happens to me, so my guess is that it has to do something with vim interpreting the `\` to actually escape something in the macro itself, but I don't know how to check my assertion.

Comment: Does not fail for me, try with `vim -Nu NONE` and if it works have a look at http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/1821

Comment: Thanks, it was a plugin, I didn't expect that.. [pangloss](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript)

Comment: As a rule of thumbs, always check with no configuration. :)

Comment: You may find the `[y` operator from [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) useful.

Comment: I know you have this figured out now, but for the future, the better way would be to use a search and replace. `:%s/"/\\"/g`